# A better way to structure a Mongoose connection module

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have refactored some code to place all my `mongoose.createConnection(...)` in a single file.  This file is then `required` in other files that use connections to the various databases specified.  The connections are lazily created and are used in both an http server and in utility scripts.

The connection file looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var serverString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var userDBString = "/USER";
var customerDBString = "/CUSTOMER";

var userConnection = null;
exports.getUserConnection = function () {
    if (userConnection === null) {
        userConnection = mongoose.createConnection(serverString + userDBString, {server: { poolSize: 4 }});
    }
    return userConnection;
};

var customerConnection = null;
exports.getCustomerConnection = function () {
    if (customerConnection === null) {
        customerConnection = mongoose.createConnection(serverString + customerDBString, { server: { poolSize: 4 }});
    }
    return customerConnection;
};
```

My models are stored in a separate files (based on their DB) that looks a bit like this:

```
exports.UserSchema = UserSchema; //Just assume I know how to define a valid schema
exports.UserModel = connection.getUserConnection().model("User", UserSchema);
```

Later , I use the `getUserConnection()` to refer to the connection I have created to actually do work the model.

**TL;DR**

In utilities that use this connection format, I have to call

```
connection.getUserConnection().on("open", function() {

  logger.info("Opened User DB");
  //Do What I Need To Do

});
```

It is possible that in some scenarios the task processor will have already broadcast the `open` event.  In some, it won't be guaranteed to have happened yet.  I noticed that it doesn't queue work if the connection isn't open (specifically, `dropCollection`) so I feel stuck.

How can I be certain that the connection is open before proceeding given that I can't depend on subscribing to the open event before the task processor runs?

Is there a better pattern for centralizing the managing of multiple connections?

Comment: So if you just interact with the database using mongoose Models, mongoose will internally queue operations until the connection is established. Is there a specific reason you can't just use that as intended and feel you need to code your own alternative approach?

Comment: I was under the same impression about queueing - I have found that it doesn't queue stuff that I call on the collection.db object (dropCollection in my case).  This may be the only exception, in which case I can live with it but... I would really like to test the connection object to see if it is open and then if not, register the `open` event listener.

Comment: I may have just answered my own question.  Does connection.readyState===1 when the db is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer part of my own question

> How can I be certain that the connection is open before proceeding
>   given that I can't depend on subscribing to the open event before the
>   task processor runs?

```
if (connection.getUserConnection().readyState!==1) {
    logger.info("User connection was not open yet. Adding open listener");
    connection.getSR26Connection().on("open", function () {
        logger.info("User open event received");
        doStuff();
    });
} else {
    logger.info("User is already open.");
    doStuff();
}

function doStuff() {
  logger.info("Doing stuff");
}
```

If you see a better way then please comment or offer up an answer.  I would still like to hear how other people manage connections without rebuilding the connection every time.